# IIS: Add public certificate for other top level domain

Tags: certificate, https, iis, iis-7, drupal

I have a Drupal Web Server running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7. The certificate is about to expire so we got another certificate, but it is for *.gov. Our original website is www.xyz.org as well as the original certificate. We had public DNS mappings for www.xyz.gov for years. I've added the the new issues certificate for *.gov to IIS and changed the https bindings 443 (local and external IPs) to point to the new certificate.

The problem I am facing is that while viewing the page at the `https ://www.xyz.gov` domain, the certificate seems to be accepted correctly but the page doesn't display right. It seems that the jacascript is not running and most images do not display.

Also, would it be possible to have the old certificate to work as well for `https: //www.xyz.org` until it expires?

Comment: With IIS 7.5 (2008R2), you don't have support for SNI, so you cannot use multiple certificates for different domains. 2012/2012R2 do support SNI, so you could set up a secondary binding using the .org domain as the SNI, but this requires at least IIS 8.